# Python IndexError: list index out of range. Cannot access by index

Tags: python, pyserial, index-error

I am using `pySerial` to read TTL byte stream. To read two bytes:

```
CheckSumByte = [ b for b in ser.read(2)]
print( CheckSumByte)
print( type(CheckSumByte))
print( str(len(CheckSumByte)))
print( CheckSumByte[0])
```

Output:

```
[202, 87]
<class 'list'>
2
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I cannot access any elements of `CheckSumByte` by index (0 or 1). What is wrong?

Here is my code:

```
while(ReadBufferCount < 1000):
    time.sleep(0.00002)
    InputBuffer = ser.inWaiting()
    if (InputBuffer > 0):
        FirstByte = ser.read(1)
        if ord(FirstByte) == 0xFA:
            while ser.inWaiting() < 21: pass
        IndexByte = ser.read(1)
        SpeedByte = [ b for b in ser.read(2)]
        DataByte0 = [ b for b in ser.read(4)]
        DataByte1 = [ b for b in ser.read(4)]
        DataByte2 = [ b for b in ser.read(4)]
        DataByte3 = [ b for b in ser.read(4)]
        CheckSumByte = [ b for b in ser.read(2)]
        print( CheckSumByte[0]) #Out of Range??`
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-5233b0a578b1>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Blair/Documents/Python/Neato XV-11 Lidar/Serial9.py', wdir='C:/Users/Blair/Documents/Python/Neato XV-11 Lidar')

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 682, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 85, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Blair/Documents/Python/Neato XV-11 Lidar/Serial9.py", line 88, in <module>
    print( CheckSumByte[0]) #Out of Range??

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Kenny: Thanks. Even simpler for the two bytes:

```
    CheckSumByte.append(ser.read(1))
    CheckSumByte.append(ser.read(1))
```

Works properly, but awkward. The items are type bytes. How to add items to the list using list comprehension? I would like to avoid the append function because it is slow.

I notice it does not work when the items of CheckSumByte are integer. Does Python 3 list comprehension require special format to add the bytes as byte (not convert to integer)?

Comment: Could you show the full traceback?

Comment: What happens if you loop thru ser.read(2) and print the results - for b in ser.read(2): print(b, type(b))

Comment: user1245262 - I like your idea. I cannot get the right syntax:        CheckSumByte = [ b for b in ser.read(2):
            print(b, type(b))]

Comment: Is your instance of `Serial` in non-blocking mode?

Comment: Your code block wasn't indented properly in the Stack Overflow markdown.  I made the simplest change I could to fix it.  Please verify that the body of the `while(ReadBufferCount < 1000):` loop is correct.

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question to produce a [mcve]... at least, to the extent you can considering there's a serial port involved.  If you can produce the same errors using only hard-coded `bytes` in place of the data read from the port, even better.

Comment: Blair, for user1245262's comment, use the for loop *instead* of a list comprehension. You can initialize CheckSumByte = [] and append b to it inside the for loop. The for loop may be clunky in comparison but it gives you an easy place to look at intermediate stuff.

Comment: : Serial is blocking

Comment: ser = serial.Serial(port=PortName, baudrate=115200,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=0)

Answer (score 2):

According to your most recent comment you have constructed `ser` as:

```
ser = serial.Serial(
    port=PortName, baudrate=115200, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, 
    timeout=0)
```

According to the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial) this means that `ser` is **non-blocking** (despite your assertion it is blocking!).

As it is in non-blocking mode there is absolutely no reason to expect `ser.read(n)` to return exactly `n` bytes.  Instead, if you wish to read `n` bytes you should either:

- construct `ser` as blocking (use `timeout=None`) in the constructor; or
- loop while monitoring the number of bytes actually read (just as you would when reading a network socket)

The latter for example means that if you wish to read `n` bytes you will need to do something like:

```
def read_exactly(ser, n):
    bytes = b""

    while len(bytes) < n:
        bytes += ser.read(n - len(bytes))

    return bytes
```

In your particular case, you seem to be monitoring the the input buffer to ensure there is adequate data for the following reads.  But this monitoring is only occurring *some* of the time, not *all* of the time.  Thus when `FirstByte != 0xFA` you could exhaust the read buffer unless you take one of the approachs given above.