# Getting IndexError when reading serial port reply

Tags: python, pyserial

I am running into a problem with a Python module for the SDS011 air quality sensor and I'm not well versed enough to know how to solve this issue.

Generally, the code is working fine, but occasionally - like once every day or so - the code throws out a "IndexError: index out of range" which causes my python app to stop.

The error according to the traceback printout occurs in the sds011.py file in this routine:

```
def _get_reply(self):
    """Read reply from device."""
    raw = self.ser.read(size=10)
    data = raw[2:8]
    if len(data) == 0:
        return None
    if (sum(d for d in data) & 255) != raw[8]:
        return None  #TODO: also check cmd id
    return raw
```

This code for this routine can be found at github here:  https://github.com/ikalchev/py-sds011/

The error occurs on the line

```
if (sum(d for d in data) & 255) != raw[8]:
```

What is the problem here and how can I handle this properly?

Comment: `raw[8]` must be indexing out of bounds for whatever reason, perhaps throw a `try`/`except` block around that in case you don't get enough data back, and handle it however that makes sense for your application

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as duplicate of [Python IndexError: list index out of range. Cannot access by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43024879/python-indexerror-list-index-out-of-range-cannot-access-by-index)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably this:

```py
raw = self.ser.read(size=10)
```

When `self.ser` has a timeout set, this doesn't necessarily read exactly 10 bytes. It reads *up to* 10 bytes—it will be less than 10 if the timeout expires before all bytes are available. See [pySerial's documentation of `.read()`](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.read).

This explains why you're only seeing a problem once every day or so. There could be some intermittent electrical problem that *occasionally* drops some bytes. So when you access `raw[8]`, there aren't that many bytes in `raw`, and you get an `IndexError`.

You can either:

- Check if `len(data) < 10`. If so, handle the error.
- Disable the timeout by passing `timeout=None` when you initialize `self.ser`. Then `self.ser.read(10)` will always return exactly 10 bytes, *if* it ever returns at all.